# Django, get form data before is_valid?

Tags: django

I'd like to get data supplied to forms (after dealing with form prefixes.)

(I can't use `cleaned_data` because I want to get data regardless form is valid or not)

I know I can get a single field's value by

```
form_instance[field_name].value()
```

So theoretically I can get all values by

```
data = {}
for field_name, field in form_instance.fields.items():
   data.update({
      field_name: form_instance[field_name].value()
   })
```

wonder if there's a better way?

Comment: Then you don't need to be using forms.

Comment: why aren't you using `form_instance.data`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the raw value from any form's field before calling `form.is_valid()` with:

```
x = form_instance.data['field_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Overload form's init. Data is there.

```
def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
    print data
```

Comment: when field name is 'foo' , data has `form-prefix-foo-1` as a name instead if the form as form prefix, and is part of formset